# why php flush sometimes showing uncomplete data?

Tags: php

Here's my current testing script:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_start();
// do initial processing here
echo "content 1"; // send the response
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
//do expensive processing here
echo "content 2";
```

If I refresh the browser multiple times, sometimes it shows "content" and sometimes it shows "content 1". Why is that? Isn't it supposed to show "content 1" all the time? Where does the "1" go?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should leave the `ob_end_flush()` statement for last, not first in the series of *flush* statements, because it will discard the buffer.

Also, I'm not sure why you try to force that many flushes, but I believe the other two flushes are not even needed.